# How to access array elements by pointer arithmetic in Java

Tags: java, c, arrays, iterator, operators

Given the following declaration in C, I can apply '+' to the address, and access
other elements.

```
char toto[5];
```

In other words, applying this operator +

```
toto+0x04
```

Accesses a different array element in Java.

Is there another way to implement this operation in java ?

Many Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to access an element in the array by adding to a memory address?

Comment: The answer for __I can do it on X, Is there a way to do it on Y?__ is almost always YES. Do some research before posting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't add a memory address to a char array in java ;)

Comment: Yes ,that's it,  i'm trying to access an element in the array by adding to a memory address

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Why is toto[index] not adequate?

Comment: i need to translate some expressions from c in java :

Comment: like this :long a = 0x67452301;
 long b = 0xefcdab89;
 long c = 0x98badcfe;
 long d = 0x10325476;
 
 a = ((b & c) | (~b & d)) + (long)(param+0x00)) + a - 0x28955B88;
 a = ((a << 0x07) | (a >> 0x19)) + b;

Comment: in fact i need to isolate the last four byte where param is a char[]

Comment: Wow, I'd not want to maintain that. Might I be as bold as to suggest rewriting rather than hit Java until it fits?

Comment: You should post your last comments into your question and also write what you expect to happen (for those of us who don't know C well enough)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm right you want to access the element at that position in the array. You can do this in java.

```
char foo[] = new char[]{'1', '2','3','4', '5'};
char fooAtPositionFour = foo[4];
```

and assign a new value this way:

```
foo[4] = 'x';
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically no since toto+4 is an address and Java's memory management policy is quite different from C's one. However you can get *(toto+4) with toto[4] ;)

Answer (score 1):

Almost always there is another way in java to implement what you want.

You rarely process `char[]` directly. Using String and StringBuilder is preferred.

```
String toto = "hello";
String lastChar = toto.substring(4); // from the 4th character.
```

To answer your question literally. You can use the [sun.misc.Unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html) with get/putByte or get/putChar class to do pointer arithmetic, but I suggest avoiding it unless you really, really need to.

Answer (score 1):

> in fact i need to isolate the last four byte where param is a char[]

Do you need the last four bytes, or the last char? The last char then `toto[toto.length-1]`

For the last four bytes you would need to turn the char array (UTF-16 in Java, I've no idea what the encoding would be in C) into a byte array then take the last four bytes.

```
new String(toto).toBytes("THE_CHAR_ENCODING_YOU_WANT_TO_USE")
```