# bit operations in java, compared to c

Tags: java, c++, bitwise-operators

i am trying to convert a c++ software in java, however the bit operations don't produce the same results.
overview of what i am doing:
there's an ascii file with data entries, 2 bytes long, unsigned (0-65535). Now i want to convert the two-byte unsigned int in two one-byte unsigned short ints.

C++ code:

```
signed char * pINT8;
signed char ACCBuf[3];
UInt16 tempBuf[128];


tempBuf[0] = Convert::ToUInt16(line);
pINT8 = (signed char *)&tempBuf[0];
ACCBuf[0] = *pINT8;
pINT8++;
ACCBuf[1] = *pINT8;
```

Java code:

```
int[] ACCBuf = new int[6];
int[] tempBuf = new int[128];
tempBuf[0] = Integer.parseInt(line);
ACCBuf[0] = tempBuf[0] >> 8;
ACCBuf[1] = 0x00FF & tempBuf[0];
```

this two codes produce different results.
any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760676/how-to-access-array-elements-by-pointer-arithmetic-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend on the endianess of the system. The C++ code has the lower byte in `ACCBUF[0]`, if it is a little endian system. The Java code has the upper byte in `ACCBUF[0]`, no matter what hardware.

If you want to get the same result in Java, you must swap the high and low byte

```
ACCBuf[0] = 0x00FF & tempBuf[0];
ACCBuf[1] = tempBuf[0] >> 8;
```

now you will have the same bits in either Java or C++.

Another difference between the two code snippets are the types used. You have 32 bit ints in the Java code and 16 bit unsigned ints respectively 8 bit chars in C++. This isn't relevant here, but must be kept in mind, when comparing different code snippets.

Comment: actually, i try to convert the c++ code to java and not the other way round.

Comment: @user2092895 Sorry, my mistake. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: this was actually the hint I needed. THANK YOU!